# UTF-8 returns weird charaters for cyrillic alphabet

Tags: android, utf-8

I am trying to read Cyrillic character based file but got some weird result. Maybe the issue is I am trying to use UTF-8
Thats my code

```
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream,Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
```

Thats the result
[image]

That is the file link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xtDjquf1-dw1KurLm67PtLAfBQNNMKF1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110341716438544091813&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: If you want us to test this you have to place your file somwhere on the internet where we can download it. Further: why this char set. Try without.

Comment: Or try installing the BinEd plugin to Android Studio (https://bined.exbin.org/intellij-plugin/) or get other editor to show the file as raw Hex and then updated the question with the start of the file as Hex so it can be manually checked or use an online checker like https://onlineutf8tools.com/validate-utf8 to check it is utf-8

Comment: @blackapps I've added file

Comment: @Andrew I've added file

Comment: I only get a 0Kb file from that link.

Comment: Are the weird characters the first few chars?

Comment: @Andrew changed the link one more time. Checked and now I see symbols and data inside it please take a look

Comment: The link is only usable with a google account. Sorry.

Comment: That link is of google sheet's interpretation of the file, any download of that is probably a resave by google sheets, so won't be the original file. But at least it does show it is a valid file of some format (may be UTF-16? or other).

Comment: The file seems to be encoded in UTF-16-BOM (the first two chars are [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `print( 'ID товара,Название товара'.encode( 'UTF_16').decode( 'ascii', 'replace'))` yields `��ID B>20@0,0720=85 B>20@0`.  Please  [edit] your question and share a [mcve] (generally, pictures are useless).

Comment: @Andrew hm maybe. is there a way to programmatically read this CSV in UTF16?

Comment: @JosefZ  is there a way to programmatically read this CSV in UTF16?

Comment: I would use the Apache commons-csv library and then it says use the BOMInputStream to handle the BOM. see https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Handling_Byte_Order_Marks